# MSAL.js How to access SID received in other tab?

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm trying to implement MSAL in a client side library, which works pretty well so far.

Now for my next steps I'm trying to add SSO by following the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso#automatically-select-account-on-azure-ad

In this documentation it is pointed out that I can add the sid claim to the auth requests, and reuse that **sid** in my second tab when logging in.

Now my main question is: what is the process to **access the sid retrieved in tab A, and then re-use it in tab B**?

Comment: Could you provide some context around your specific implementation (including relevant code) that you are having trouble with? By setting the MSAL.js storage location to localstorage, that sid should be accessible to any tab hosted in the same domain.

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT I changed the cache location to localStorage indeed. I was under the (wrong) impression that SID was an *alternative* method of sharing login information. I now understand it's not the recommended way in my scenario. Thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll summarize for anyone else that is running into this sort of situation. The traditional way to store login tokens is in a cookie. This works fine for most scenarios- if the user tries to login to a different site on the same domain, the cookie is picked up. If they are signing in to a different domain, they will still need to visit the login page, but instead of entering their credentials they will simply be issued a new cookie for the new domain.

The question posed is for a special case when attempting to obtain a cookie on one tab, then using it on another tab *without refreshing the page in the second tab*. In this case, the token must be stored in local storage in order to be accessible to the code in the second tab immediately.